# How do I classify cytotoxicity values, whether a sample is mildly, moderately, or highly cytotoxic?

Tags: physiology, immunology, cancer

I used LDH assay for cytotoxicity testing. I have a plant extract which I tested against HepG2 cancer cells. I did three trials, my results were 2%, 6%, and 8% cytotoxicity, respectively.

How do I classify these values?

I was wondering if these values are low/mild, moderate, or high cytotoxicity. Someone told me that anything higher than 10% is already highly cytotoxic; however, I cannot find any reference that stated this.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, you should tell us: 1) what the LDH cytotoxicity assay is and what LDH stands for; and 2) if you are using a kit — from what company or if not, what protocol are you following (summarize and then provide references). Finally, please tell us what you have done to find the answer — as  it stands this seems under researched and possibly opinion-based, both of which are grounds for closure.

Comment: I hope the results are compared with the effects of the solvent alone on the cancer cells. For example, Ethanol kills cells...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear (e.g. unexplained abbreviations), under researched, and possibly opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your citations.  How do they use this assay?**

I am not familiar with the assay you used, but you are.  Probably it is used to evaluate other plant extracts.  How do those authors do it?   When other people use this assay to look at plant extracts, how do they classify their results?

Consider what has been done in the past using this assay.  Then put your results in the context of what has gone before.